# How to allow INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to pass through SQLi filter?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I'm practicing SQL injection on a test bed where the `OR` and `AND` keywords are blacklisted. Using logical operators such as `||` and `&&`, I'm able to proceed. However when trying the query below, it fails.

```
http://localhost/testbed/index1/?id=-14' || (SELECT 1,TABLE_NAME,3 FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= DATABASE()) --+
```

This may be as 'FOR' string is filtered so 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' isn't able to pass through as well. Any suggestions on how to escape this so that I can run the above query?

Comment: do compound queries work otherwise on the app?

Comment: The [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/scalar-subqueries.html) needs to be a scalar operand and thus surrounded by parenthesis.

Comment: @schroeder  Yes they do work. Anything with a 'FOR' inserted in it won't work. Ex- SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES will become SELECT * FROM INMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Comment: @Gumbo Agreed. Thanks. Did the editing,  what about the solution ?

Comment: Did you try ‘doubling’ it like `INFFORORMATION_SCHEMA`, maybe the `FOR`s are only removed once.

Comment: @Gumbo The 'OR' is filtered. Thanks for the advise. I'll try.

Comment: @Gumbo Cheers man. It worked !!!

Comment: I tried INFOORRMATION_SCHEMA and it was able to bypass.

Comment: You need to edit your question: is it "FOR" or "OR" that is filtered?

Comment: @schroeder Actually, "OR" is filtered but as "FOR" contains "OR" so "FOR" isn't allowed either.